# Как использовать одну функцию в двух компонентах?

Tags: angular2, typescript

Помогите пожалуйста избавиться от дублирования кода.

Я сделал простейшую систему входа. На страничке входа(agree) предлагается согласиться с условиями путём клика по чекбоксу. После этого пользователь получает возможность ходить по внутренним страничкам(dashboard, profile)

routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    children: [],
    component: ProfileComponent
  }, 
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    children: [],
    component: DashboardComponent
  }, 
  {
    path: 'auth',
    children: [],
    component: AuthComponent
  }, 
  {
    path: 'agree',
    children: [],
    component: AgreeComponent
  }     
];
```

agree.component.ts:

```
export class AgreeComponent implements OnInit {

    checkboxSelected: boolean = false;

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.checkAgree();  
    }

    checkAgree(): void{
        if(localStorage.iAgree == 'true') {
            this.router.navigateByUrl("/");
        }       
    };

    submitAgree(): void{
        console.log('agree is:', this.checkboxSelected);
        if(this.checkboxSelected == true) {
            localStorage.iAgree = 'true';
            this.checkAgree();
        };          
    }

}
```

dashboard.component.ts:

```
export class DashboardComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router) { 
        this.checkAgree();
    }

    checkAgree(): void{
        if(localStorage.iAgree != 'true') {
            this.router.navigateByUrl("/agree");
        }   
    };  
}
```

profile.component.ts:

```
export class ProfileComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router) { 
        this.checkAgree();
    }

    checkAgree(): void{
        if(localStorage.iAgree != 'true') {
            this.router.navigateByUrl("/agree");
        }   
    };  
}
```

Проблема в том, что функция this.checkAgree() дублируется в компонентах dashboard и profile(А в реальном проекте их будет намного больше).

[GITHUB](https://github.com/zlodiak/zlodiak.github.io)

Comment: наследование чем не нравится ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавляете функцию в сервис и подключаете этот сервис в любой нужный компонент:

**check.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CheckService {
    isCheckAgree() {
        if(localStorage.iAgree != 'true') {
            this.router.navigateByUrl("/agree");
        }   
    }; 
}
```

**dashboard.component.ts/profile.component.ts**

```
import { CheckService }         from './check.service';

export NameComponent {
  constructor(private checkService: CheckService) { }

  checkAgree(): void {
     this.checkService.isCheckAgree();
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, это работает. но если использовать, например, наследование и таким образом компоненты dashboard и profile унаследовать от общего компонента auth(в котором будет необходимый для проверки авторизации функционал), то это будет "идеологически" не верным подходом?

Comment: @cyklop77, я не очень силен в идеологии, но наследование в данном случае я представляю так: "вам нужна микроволновка, для этого вы едете в магазин и... покупаете микроволновку, пылесос и холодильник, при том, что пылесос и холодильник вам не нужны или даже уже есть", а сервис так: "вы заказываете микроволновку и вам привозят микроволновку"